# Is the "Blatantly off-topic" flag redundant now?

Tags: discussion, flags

I haven’t reached 3k rep yet so I flag questions which should be closed. For some time now, there is a new flag - “Not about programming or software development”, which, in my opinion, makes the old "Blatantly off-topic" flag redundant.

Maybe the "Blatantly off-topic" flag should be removed.

[image: flag option as of now]

Comment: It's a pre-defined option network-wide (which will change to "Other - add a comment" for those with close vote privilege), I don't think it can be disabled per-site.

Comment: *I'm trying to get my lawnmower to cut the grass at 1inch but the lever is stuck at 2cm. How can I fix that?*. Blatantly off-topic.

Comment: @rene Not about programming

Comment: @AndrewT. for example Arduino SE doesn't have the "Blatantly off-topic" flag (or maybe I don't see it as mod?)

Comment: @Juraj because you already have close vote privilege (also note that for those who have close vote privilege, they can't flag questions for closure, and the options will be replaced with close vote options instead). This is what [users without close vote privilege see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXgF6.png).

Comment: Related on MSE: [Blatantly off-topic for all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310575/241919), [Why are there two different close reasons for questions that aren't about the site's topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300056/241919)

Comment: so the "Not about programming or software development" is a close reason and the "Blatantly off-topic" is hard-coded

Comment: there is no corresponding close reason for " Blatantly off-topic" so people who handle the queues or SOVCR must then choose one. and now they choose "Not about programming or software development" I guess.

Comment: The corresponding close reason for "Blatantly off-topic" is "Other" which we do occasionally use. A programming question that is not in English is a probably a fair example of a question where "Not about programming" would _not_ be applicable but custom could be. (Yes, people tend to also use Needs Details or Clarity for content that is Not in English, but I don't think that means that Blatantly off-topic or Other would be wrong options in those cases)

Comment: I thought the "Blatantly off-topic" is a site close reason. Now when I know it is added by system, I searched Meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300056/why-are-there-two-different-close-reasons-for-questions-that-arent-about-the-si

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**The "blatantly off-topic" flag option is a standard network-wide flag option**, analogous to free-input custom close reason for those who have close vote privilege. This is because *on most SE sites, there is no custom close reason used as a catch-all reason (especially for private beta sites that have just launched).*

The option is only shown when users try to *flag a question for closure*. Note that for users who already have the close vote privilege, the option will be replaced with "Other - add a comment" since they *cannot flag* a question for closure anymore and instead *must vote from existing custom close reasons or provide their own*, and they may not be aware of this flagging option before.

As far as I know, this flagging option is not considered as per-site setting.

Answer (score 6):

**No, it's not redundant.**

There are varying degrees of being off-topic.  As users increasingly push the boundaries of the vast off-topic space, we need more flags to express the degree of off-topicness, not less.  Let's also add:

1. **Subtly off-topic**

   If one thinks about it long enough, the minor reason for being off-topic may become evident.
2. **Secretly off-topic**

   For reasons undocumented and for reasons that will not be further explained, this question is off-topic.  It just is.  Don't ask.  It's a secret.
3. **Egregiously off-topic**

   The question is *even more* off-topic than *blatantly off-topic*.
4. **Disgustingly off-topic**

   Imagine multiple prospective answerers across the world violently vomiting after reading your question.  It's that off-topic.

These new flags are needed to counter the onslaught of off-topic questions before us, and it should be *blatantly* obvious that the **blatantly off-topic** reason is *blatantly not* redundant.

Comment: [Not sure if serious](https://media.tenor.com/s1wnF2DiWA0AAAAM/skeptical-futurama.gif).

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satire).  I chuckled about there being a ***blatantly off-topic*** flag and sought to extend the idea and my amusement further.  Sorry if it fell flat for you.

Comment: I believe for Disgustingly off-topic is where you consider red flags (rude/abusive or spam) rather than blatently off topic.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Close reasons are not mutually exclusive. One or more can apply.

For any question that resembles something that might involve software / tools / algorithm if you use all your imagination but is still not in scope for Stack Overflow, use "Not about programming or software development".

For statements about kittens, use "Blatantly off-topic."

Comment: *Especially* [Schrödinger's kittens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrFa4tXTQQk&t=1m43s).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I tried to watch that video but every time I heard "very quantum" I thought of a doge saying "much quantum"...

Comment: Oh, you have the same [flag description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4hsV.png) as me. I don't know why it's different for other users :-D